# Multiset without Compare?

Tags: c++, templates, multiset

I want to use `multiset` to count some custom defined keys. The keys are not comparable numerically, comparing two keys does not mean anything, but their equality can be checked.

I see that `multiset` template wants a `Compare` to order the multiset. The order is not important to me, only the counts are important. If I omit `Compare` completely what happens? Does multiset work without any problems for my custom keys? If I cannot use `std::multiset` what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `std::multiset` if you don't have a strict weak ordering. Your options are:

1. Impose a strict-weak ordering on your data. If your key is a "linear" data structure, it is usually a good idea to compare it lexicographically.
2. Use an unordered container equivalent, e.g., `boost::unordered_multiset`. For that, you will need to make your custom data-type hash-able, which is often-times easier than imposing some kind of order.

Comment: `unordered_multiset` is what I am looking for

Answer (score 4):

If you can only compare keys for equality then you cannot use `std::multiset`. For associative containers your key type must have a *strict weak ordering* imposed by a comparison operation.

The *strict weak ordering* doesn't necessarily have to be numerical.

[For use in an associative container, you don't actually need an equality comparison. Key equivalence is determined by `!compare(a, b) && !compare(b, a)`.]

If you *really* can't define an ordering for your keys then your only option is to use an sequence container of key-value pairs and use an linear search for lookup. Needless to say this will be less efficient for set like operations than a `multiset` so you should probably try hard to create an ordering if at all possible.

Comment: If you can use C++0x features, then `std::unordered_multimap` might also be an option. The hashing function does not have to provide an ordering, just identical values for identical keys and a reasonable probability of different values for different keys.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: True, although I'm finding it hard to think of a situation where you could provide suitable input for such a hashing function without being able to get a full order in any case.

Comment: You get only a partial order if you use only part of the key for the hash function. And if you want to be perverse (and accept the likely performance penalties), you could let the hash function just return a constant.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: My point was that in practice, if you have the input to feed to a hash function why not just use all the bytes that you feed to the hash to determine the complete order? I agree that it's theoretically possible to have a good has with no complete order, but will it ever occur in practice?

Comment: I can see it happening easily if you have a unique ID in your data that the hash function only uses that (perhaps in an identity transformation). And using only part of the data will usually not give a perfect hash, but it might be sufficient for a significantly lower cost than a perfect hash.

Comment: @Bart: but in that case, you do have a complete ordering as well. His question is if you can come up with a situation where you can compute a good hash, *without* being able to order your data.

Comment: As data is always formed from a set of bytes, you can *always* create some complete ordering. What may not always be possible is have an ordering that is meaningful for the entity being modelled. To get back to the unique ID's, what does it mean that ID A is greater than ID B?  Although a good hash function gives you some kind of ordering for the data, that is essentially just an implementation detail. You don't have to deal with the mindshift of comparing two entities that are conceptually non-comparable.  Judging from the comment on the accepted answer, this was what the OP was dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

If you omit the `Compare` completely, it will get the default value, which is `less` (which gives the result of the `<` operator applied to your key) - which may or may not even compile for your key.

The reason for having an ordering is that it allows the implementation to look up elements more quickly by their key (when inserting, deleting etc), To understand why, imagine looking words up in a dictionary. Traditional dictionaries use alphabetical order, which makes words easy to look up. If you were preparing a dictionary for a language that isn't easily ordered  - say a pictographic language - then either it would be very hard to find words in it at all (you'd have to search the whole dictionary), or you'd try to find a logical way to order them (e.g. by putting all the pictures that can be drawn with one pen stroke first, then two lines, etc...) - because even if this order was completely arbitrary, it would make finding entries in the dictionary far more efficient.

Similarly, even if your keys don't need to be ordered for your own purposes, and don't have any natural order, you can usually define an ordering that is good enough to address these concerns. The ordering must be transitive (if `a<b` and `b<c` then `a<c`), and strict (never return true for `a<a`), asymmetric (`a<b` and `b>a` never both true). Ideally it should order all elements (if `a` & `b` are different then either `a<b` or `b<a`), though you can get away with that not being true (ie a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)) - though that's rather technical.

Indeed, perhaps the most obvious use for it is the rare case where it is completely impossible to order the items - in which case you can supply a comparison operator which always returns false. This will very likely result in poor performance, but will at least function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two important criteria which you listed.

1. You don't care about order
2. comparison of keys do not mean anything

and one assumed,

1. the fact that you are using `multiset` implies that there are many instances

So, why not use `std::vector` or `std::deque` or `std::list`? then you can take advantage of the various algorithms that can use the equality check (such as `count_if` etc.)

Comment: As I said, I need the count of the keys.

Comment: @nimcap, hence the use of the `count_if` algorithm - which requires a full iteration...

Comment: I know but, it will be expensive to reconstruct the counts separately in my case